# jquery how to know when the date selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using this official date picker

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

it works nice. when i click on the text field, the date selector appears.

I want to know how to catch the event then the user click on the date.

Thanks

#### Sorry i forget to tell that I am using asp.net so I need to fire a function there

Comment: It's in the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').on('change',function() {
    // date has changed. Do stuff...
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg83M/18/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1 to you. but please check my edit question, i am using asp.net so i need to fire a function in the code behind c#

Comment: Change event will also fire if we write something on textbox

Comment: @user2226785 sorry, I don't know much .net

Comment: @3rror404 Try typing 12 and remove focus from datepicker .

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onSelect: function (date) {
        alert('Date selected');
        //you action is here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1 to you. but please check my edit question, i am using asp.net so i need to fire a function in the code behind c#

Answer (score 2):

You can use the datepicker's `onSelect()` event:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
  // Do what you need
  }
});
```

EDIT: If you need to pick this up in the C# code behind, I'd say the simplest method is to use the textchanged event on the field you attached the datepicker to. Something like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatePicker" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtDatePicker_TextChanged" CssClass="datepicker" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

And on the server side, doing something like this:

```
protected void txtDatePicker_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime pickedDate = DateTime.Parse(txtDatePicker.Text); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1 to you. but please check my edit question, i am using asp.net so i need to fire a function in the code behind c#

Answer (score 0):

Try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg83M/16/) [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg83M/17/)

```
$(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      $('#datepicker').change(function(){
             var tem = $(this).val();
              alert(tem);
      });
  });
```

OR

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker().change(function(){
     var tem = $(this).val();
     alert(tem);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Change event will also fire if we write something on textbox

Comment: I am attaching datepicker to that textbox so,whenever i do something it first open the datepicker check the demo

Comment: Try typing 12 and remove focus from datepicker .

Answer (score 0):

onSelect callback event will select the data, in which you can put your code.

```
$("#myDatePicker").datepicker({
    // set options
    onSelect: function (date) {
        console.log(date);
        //you action is here
    }
});
```

You can find the details here : http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect